# redux toolkit and reselect

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit, reselect

I want to use reselect but I do not understand it correctly yet.

If I want to filter anything then I can do this:

```
const selectNumCompletedTodos = createSelector(
  (state) => state.todos,
  (todos) => todos.filter((todo) => todo.completed).length
)
```

But if I fetch, how does it look then? (I use useSelector and not mapToProps)

My Code:

Login:

```
imports
...
const Login = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [passwordShown, setPasswordShown] = useState(true);

  const handleGoBack = () => {
    navigation.goBack();
  };

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    const payload = {
      email,
      password
    };
    dispatch(request(payload));
  };
  return (
   <View>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleLogin}>
       <Text>click to fetch!</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
  )
```

authSaga.js

```
import { all, call, put, take, takeEvery, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { request, authSuccess, authFailure } from '../slice/authSlice';
import authAPI from '../../api/auth';
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';

function* auth({ payload }) {
  const data = yield call(authAPI, payload);
   yield put(authSuccess(data.user));
}

function* watcher() {
  yield takeEvery(request.type, auth);
}

export default function* () {
  yield all([watcher()]);
}
```

reducers:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import authReducer from './slice/authSlice';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: authReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Slice:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {
    loading: false,
    data: [],
    error: null
  },
  reducers: {
    request(state) {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    authSuccess(state, action) {
      state.loading = false;
      state.data = action.payload;
    },
    authFailure(state, action) {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

export const { request, authSuccess, authFailure } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

can anyone help me ?

................................................................................

Comment: What is the `request` in your login code `dispatch(request(payload));`?

Comment: @RishabhGupta I editet my code above. I fetch the data correctly but I want it to use with reselect so thats not rerender every time do you now how it works?